# Column selection for selected cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to select the hole column (e.g. "A:A") according to the selected cell. So far, I've got to this point:

```
function floatingrange() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var thisSheet = sheet.getName();

 var a1 = sheet.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation();
 var justA = a1.slice(0, 1);
 var rangeAA = sheet.getRange("justA:justA");
 Logger.log(rangeAA);
}
```

It turns out that the A1 notation won't accept a variable for its composition. Does anybody knows how to deal with this issue properly? I'm new to the gig, so I'm having a hard time here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your variable `justA` is the column you want to select, you can just:

```
// change this
var rangeAA = sheet.getRange("justA:justA");

// to this
var rangeAA = sheet.getRange(`${justA}:${justA}`);
```

Explanation: This uses [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach often leads to the problem of having to remove a bunch of nulls from the bottom of data to maxRows.  It's actually much better to use the other signature method that uses row,column,number of rows,number of columns which can be done this way for a complete column `sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);` or even this way `Sheet.getRange(1,1,Sheet.getLastRow());

Comment: But you can also use `Sheet.getRange( 'A1:A'+Sheet.getLastRow());`

Comment: Got it. For the specific function in which I'm using this section, I intend to capture the nulls as well. Propably that is why I didn't find people doing it the way I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> It turns out that the A1 notation won't accept a variable for its composition.

The above affirmation is wrong. `"justA:justA"` is not a variable, it's a string but there it's not a valid A1 notation.

To use `justA` variable to build a valid A1 notation string, one way is to use

```
var rangeAA = sheet.getRange(justA + ":" + justA);
```

If your project is using the new runtime (V8) you could also use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

Comment: Ok, I used this concatenation and it seems to work just fine. I will try to learn about template strings as well. I thought that a string containing the name of a variable would call that variable, but it seems that things doesn't work this way. Thank you for the help.